# get respective div element under same class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a main document div to add some html element through variable `"str"`

```
<div id='documentDiv'></div>
```

I have a functionality which will add some html element to my `#documentDiv`.

```
var str="<div class='customElement'></div><a href='' onclick='append(event);'>append</a>"
```

And I have a functionality to append `str` to `documentDiv` as many time I want:

```
 $('#documentDiv').append(str);
```

after appending two times I have the same structure appended twice inside my documentDiv element

```
<div id='documentDiv'>
   <div class='customElement'></div><a href='' onclick='append(event);'>append</a> // want to append some text to respective .customElement div
   <div class='customElement'></div><a href='' onclick='append(event);'>append</a>
</div>
```

My problem is with onclick ,i want to append something inside the ***respective div*** under `customElement` class.But with onClick ,***it always gets appended to the first div***.How can i get respective div element using jquery?

```
function append(event){
   $('.customElement').append("some text");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could help you:
Without a-tag:

```
$('.customElement').bind('click',function(){
    $(this).append("some text"); 
});
```

or with a-tag:

```
$('.customElement a').bind('click',function(){
    $(this).parent().append("some text"); 
});
```

Comment: click event is attached to anchor element.Why should i bind a click event to ( .customElement) class? i want by clicking on any anchor tag ,,some text will be appended to respective element under (.customElement) class

Comment: I'm not sure, what you want to do, but maybe thats better:

$('.customElement a').bind('click',function(){
    $(this).parent().append("some text"); 
});

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to use this.

```
function append(event){
   $(this).append("some text");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding your elements dynamically you should delegate the events by adding the `on` method to the parent element.

Here is an example.

```js
function append(event){
   $(this).prev().append("some text");
   event.preventDevault();
}

$('#documentDiv').on('click', 'a', append);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='documentDiv'>
   <div class='customElement'></div><a href='#'>append</a>
   <div class='customElement'></div><a href='#'>append</a>
</div>
```